# Errors in Microdata for image/logo as part of a BlogPosting

Tags: html, blogs, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am having an issue getting a publisher logo and blog post image to validate using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

Some sample markup of what I currently have is:

```
 <article class="post" itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
     <div class="preview">
         <h2 itemprop="mainEntityOfPage headline"><a href="/blog/improving-the-patient-experience-through-the-revenue-cycle-part-1">Improving the Patient Experience through the Revenue Cycle Part 1</a></h2>
         <div class="meta">
         <span itemprop="datePublished" class="published-date">Friday, February 19, 2016</span>
         <span class="sep">|</span>
         <span itemprop="author" class="author"><a title="Posts by Laurie Shoaf" href="/blog/?author=Laurie+Shoaf">Laurie Shoaf</a></span>
         <span class="sep">|</span>
         <span class="category"><a title="Posts in Revenue Cycle Management" href="/blog/?category=Revenue+Cycle+Management">Revenue Cycle Management</a></span>
         <span class="sep">|</span>
         <span class="comments"><a title="Improving the Patient Experience through the Revenue Cycle Part 1 Comments" href="/blog/improving-the-patient-experience-through-the-revenue-cycle-part-1#comments">Comments<span class="hide" itemprop="discussionUrl">/blog/improving-the-patient-experience-through-the-revenue-cycle-part-1#comments</span></a></span>
         </div>
         <p itemprop="description" class="snippet">This three part series will focus on strategies to augment revenue cycle operations in order to improve the patient experience. In the coming weeks we will share methods designed to enhance patient communications and ideas for maximizing performance when using an early-out or extended business offic...</p>
         <a itemprop="url" class="btn blue" href="/blog/improving-the-patient-experience-through-the-revenue-cycle-part-1">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
         <span class="hide" itemscope="" itemprop="publisher" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">CCi</span><img itemprop="logo" src="/media/cci-small.png" alt="CCi Logo" title="CCi | Power on the Inside" /></span>
         <span class="hide" itemprop="dateModified">2/19/2016</span>
         <img itemprop="image" src="/media/blog featured/blog-post.png" class="hide" alt="Blog Post Graphic" title="Improving the Patient Experience through the Revenue Cycle Part 1" />
     </div>
    </article>
```

The errors I am receiving on the testing side are:

- publisher -> logo : The attribute itemtype has an invalid value.
- image: A value for the image field is required.

What is the proper way to nest these properties in a "blogPost" schema to pass validation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schema.org NewsArticle: invalid value for logo property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135578/schema-org-newsarticle-invalid-value-for-logo-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, Google wants to see an `ImageObject` item (for displaying their [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles)).

```
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <!-- … -->
</div>

<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <!-- … -->
</div>
```

Comment: Aha, that did the trick--I had to add some nested hidden spans, but that item type worked.