# Schema.org NewsArticle: invalid value for logo property

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I try to markup a little section in my code as `NewsArticle` but I can't get it to validate.

If I do this

```
<div itemscope itemprop="publisher" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <span itemprop="name">My Company</span>
</div>
```

the validator complains that there is no `logo`.

And if I add a `logo` like this

```
<div itemscope itemprop="publisher" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <img itemprop="logo" src="https://www.mysite.de/resources/assets/71/small/my_logo_web.png" />
  <span itemprop="name">My Company</span>
</div>
```

the validator complains that the attribute contains an invalid value. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your markup is valid HTML5+Microdata and you are using the Schema.org vocabulary appropriately.

With "validator", you probably refer to [Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). Note that errors shown in this tool [don’t necessarily mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669) that your markup is wrong; they often mean that you won’t get a certain Google search result feature unless you provide certain properties.

If you want to get this search result feature in Google Search (e.g., the [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles)), you [have to provide an `ImageObject` item as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920324/1591669) (instead of a URL value) for the `logo` property.

```html
<div itemscope itemprop="publisher" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">

  <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="url" src="https://www.mysite.de/resources/assets/71/small/my_logo_web.png" />
    <!-- and Google probably requires some more properties here, e.g. "height" and "width" -->
  </div>

  <span itemprop="name">My Company</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you absolutely read my mind. I apologize for letting you guess. You can't imagine how much you've just helped me. Thanks a lot!