# Schema markup relating to data outside of div

Tags: schema, schema.org, microdata

I know this can be done - but I just can't find an example.

I have an Schema.org Organization div in the header of my page.

The page is an article so I have to add a publisher. I don't want to duplicate data and I know that you can refer to other items on the page by ID but I'm just not sure of the overall syntax.

This is where I'm at. I'm still getting 2 errors, stating that the logo and name fields are required - but isn't that what I'm referencing?

```
<div id="organization" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHome" runat="server" itemprop="url">
        <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" itemprop="logo" />
    </asp:HyperLink>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="My Co" /> 
</div>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="organization"></span>
</article>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Microdata - itemref to another itemscope (Person works for Organization)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186058/html5-microdata-itemref-to-another-itemscope-person-works-for-organization) (in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33984412/1591669), I linked to many examples)

Comment: @unor - the concept is the same but its a slightly different scenario and I'm still getting validation errors which ever way I try. Do add the itemref to the article or the publisher?

Comment: Then your question seems to be about your specific problem -- in which case you have to include the markup in your question. Regarding where to place the `itemref` attribute: see [the "tl;dr" in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33984412/1591669)

Comment: @unor - I've added markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984412/1591669), the element you want to add has to have the `itemprop` attribute. So this is the structure you need:

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="organization">
</div>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="organization">
</article>
```

(This should only be used on pages where the `Organization` is added as `publisher`; otherwise it’s invalid HTML+Microdata if the `itemprop="publisher"` doesn’t belong to an `itemscope`.)

If you now replace the `<asp:…>` elements with actual HTML elements, Google’s SDTT is able to understand what you want to convey: it adds the `name`/`url`/`logo` properties to the `Organization` item, and it adds this `Organization` item as `publisher` to the `Article` item.

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="/example">
    <img itemprop="logo" src="example.png" alt="" />
  </a>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="My Co" />
</div>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="organization">
</article>
```

The errors Google’s SDTT still reports are not actual errors with your Schema.org/Microdata. These are just properties that Google requires for getting their search result features. In the case of `logo`, [Google wants to see an `ImageObject` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36136433/1591669).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sure I'd tried this configuration before but it does seem to work now. The odd thing is that now my logo (as well as the article image) ar reporting issues - logo.itemtype has an invalid value. Before the change the logo validated fine.