# Warning that "image" and "logo" have wrong values

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I've added Schema.org on my blog list with JSON-LD:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BlogPosting",
    "headline": "Fixer la navigation Off-Canvas sur Foundation",
    "image": "https://stephane-richin.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/S/foundation-website.jpg",
    "author": "Stéphane Richin",
    "datePublished": "2015-02-03",
    "dateModified": "2015-02-03",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Stéphane Richin",
        "url": "http://stephane-richin.fr",
        "logo" : "http://stephane-richin.fr/images/logo/logo-stephane-richin.svg"
    },
    "mainEntityOfPage": "True"
}
```

But, I've 2 warnings on `image` and `logo`:

> image.itemtype has wrong value
>
> logo.itemtype has wrong value

Do you have any idea why image and logo have wrong values?

Comment: Same questions/problem with Microdata: [*Schema.org NewsArticle: invalid value for logo property*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36135578/1591669) · [*Errors in Microdata for image/logo as part of a BlogPosting*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35919866/1591669)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like in order to pass the Structured Data Testing Tool you need to use `ImageObject` as a *required* property of `image` and `publisher.logo`.

From their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types):

> **image** - [ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject), required

Your final code will look like:

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"BlogPosting",
    "headline":"Fixer la navigation Off-Canvas sur Foundation",
    "image": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
      "height": 800,
      "width": 800
    },
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Stéphane Richin"
    },
    "datePublished":"2015-02-03",
    "dateModified":"2015-02-03",
    "publisher": {
        "@type":"Organization",
        "name":"Stéphane Richin",
        "url":"http://stephane-richin.fr",
        "logo": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
          "width": 600,
          "height": 60
        }
    },
    "mainEntityOfPage": "True"
}
```

I also amended it to recognise the author as [Person schema](https://schema.org/Person).