# Google structured data

Tags: structured-data

Before I ask I would like to mention that I have searched for solution...

I am trying to build Goggle's AMP page. I used their template and tested it with Chrome's Developer Tools, however, in Google's own Structured Data Testing Tool I get an error and two warnings. I'm stuck trying to figure this thing out. Here's my code and below is a screen capture of the errors I see.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "headline": "Remote Card Sorting and Prioritization Matrix Tools for usability testing and information architecture.",
    "datePublished": "2016-10-08T12:02:41Z",
    "dateModified": "2016-11-05T12:02:41Z",
    "author": "usabiliTEST",
    "image": [
      "/i/usabilitestLogo.png"
    ],
    "publisher": "usabiliTEST"
  }
</script>
```

How can this be fixed? What am I still missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image needs to be an 'Image Object'.

```
"image": {
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
  "height": 800,
  "width": 800
},
```

[I answered a similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40159746/3337722)

Comment: I think Google test tool is broken. Webmaster tool says no errors, but the tool is all over the place.